# Graph (k − 1)-connected contracting a k-connected graph

Tags: graph, graph-theory

I need help proving this problem:

**Let G be a k-connected graph. Prove that if G' is obtained from a graph G by contracting an edge, then G' is (k − 1)-connected.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: ummm...and so? why does that bother you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you contracted node X.

Now suppose G' is not (k-1) connected. This means there are nodes {A1, A2, ..., A(k-2)}, removing which you can disconnect the graph.

Then even if node X was connected to every node in G, removing nodes {A1, A2, ..., A(k-2), X} leads to disconnecting G. Therefore, the original graph G is not k-connected, which contradicts the original statement, which ends the proof.